# Insert values from excel in mysql WordPress Php

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this php code that is suppose to insert data from excel file to mysql database, from wordpress. This is the code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
 $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'excelvalues'; 
echo $table_name;
if(isset($_POST["submit_file"]))
{
 $file = "example.csv"//$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
 $file_open = fopen($file,"r");
 while(($csv = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
 {
 $Anrede = $csv[0];
 $Titel = $csv[1];
 $Nachname = $csv[2];
 $Vorname = $csv[3];
 $Strasse = $csv[4];
 $LKZ = $csv[5];
 $PLZ = $csv[6];
 $Ort = $csv[7];
 $Mobil = $csv[8];
 $Email = $csv[9];
 $Geburtsdatum = $csv[10];
 $Eintrittsdatum = $csv[11];
 $Prüfungsjahr = $csv[12];
 $Vermittlung = $csv[13];
 $Bezirk = $csv[14];
 $Kartennummer = $csv[15];
 $LinkQR = $csv[16];
 $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name(ID, Anrede, Titel,Nachname,Vorname,Strasse,LKZ,PLZ,Ort,Mobil,Email,Geburtsdatum,Eintrittsdatum,Prüfungsjahr,Vermittlung,Bezirk,Kartennummer,LinkQR) VALUES(NULL, '$Anrede', '$Titel', '$Nachname', '$Vorname', '$Strasse', '$LKZ', '$PLZ', '$Ort', '$Mobil', '$Email', '$Geburtsdatum', '$Eintrittsdatum', '$Prüfungsjahr', '$Vermittlung', '$Bezirk', '$Kartennummer', '$LinkQR')");
 }
 }
 ?>
```

The code works it inserts values on the database but the values are only the number of rows from excel but the values are missing, i dont understand what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you retrieved the row id to each variable. This should work -

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'excelvalues'; 

if(isset($_POST["submit_file"])){
    $csvFile = file( 'example.csv' );
    $all_data = [];
        
    // fetch all data to array
    foreach( $csvFile as $line ){
        $all_data[] = str_getcsv( $line );
    }
        
    // fetch data from each row
    foreach( $all_data as $row_key => $rows ){
            
        // fetch data from each column
        $Anrede = $rows[0];
        $Titel = $rows[1];
        $Nachname = $rows[2];
        $Vorname = $rows[3];
        $Strasse = $rows[4];
        $LKZ = $rows[5];
        $PLZ = $rows[6];
        $Ort = $rows[7];
        $Mobil = $rows[8];
        $Email = $rows[9];
        $Geburtsdatum = $rows[10];
        $Eintrittsdatum = $rows[11];
        $Prüfungsjahr = $rows[12];
        $Vermittlung = $rows[13];
        $Bezirk = $rows[14];
        $Kartennummer = $rows[15];
        $LinkQR = $rows[16];
            
        // Insert into table
        $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO $table_name(ID, Anrede, Titel,Nachname,Vorname,Strasse,LKZ,PLZ,Ort,Mobil,Email,Geburtsdatum,Eintrittsdatum,Prüfungsjahr,Vermittlung,Bezirk,Kartennummer,LinkQR) VALUES(NULL, '$Anrede', '$Titel', '$Nachname', '$Vorname', '$Strasse', '$LKZ', '$PLZ', '$Ort', '$Mobil', '$Email', '$Geburtsdatum', '$Eintrittsdatum', '$Prüfungsjahr', '$Vermittlung', '$Bezirk', '$Kartennummer', '$LinkQR')");
    }
}
```